# Is the https binding enough to access the secure link?

Tags: c#, soap, asmx

I am testing my webservice for http and https by setting the end points from the c# code and not the app.config.

I have only http setup to test but not the https.

So, is my code fine to access the https link?

```
var bindingHttp = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding { Name = "SI_FunctionalLocation_In_AsyncSoap", Namespace = "system.serviceModel" };

var bindingHttps = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpsBinding(System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport){ Name = "SI_FunctionalLocation_In_AsyncSoap", Namespace = "system.serviceModel" };


var endPointHttp = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://localhost:2755/SI_FunctionalLocation_In_Async.asmx");
var endPointHttps = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://10.171.101.124/SI_Functionallocation_In_Async.asmx");

SI_FunctionalLocation_In_AsyncSoapClient client = new SI_FunctionalLocation_In_AsyncSoapClient(bindingHttps, endPointHttps);
```

Also, I have created a self sign certificate in IIS but it throws exception "**the remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure**".

So, my question is that would it work for actual https link that I will be using at my client system.